# Board game about setting fairy tales right

Tags: identify-this-game

In my childhood (late '80s to early '90s) there was a board game around where you were part of sort of a book patrol. You had to set fairy tales right that went wrong.

- The main story as far as I remember was about Long John Silver and the treasure he was after. The treasure island being the map you played on.
- You gained "stars" whenever you did win out in a part of the game.
- You fought the adversaries from different stories and also tried to overcome traps while you travelled the map.
- You played as a group trying to achieve the same thing as sort of a party.

Edit:
I remember now that the stars you could use to increase your attributes. Also on some map fields there were traps where you had multiple choices (and or rolls?) which could lead to you becoming trapped, or succeeding in avoiding the trap.

One point I'm unsure about is... I always took it as a precurser (despite different setting) to *The Dark Eye* (thus maybe a Schmidt Spiele game). At least from what I remember of the box the box itself was similar to the later *Dark Eye* 1st edition boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the meantime. The game was called:
***Der Geheimbund des Schwarzen Auges***   and nicknamed ***DSA Junior***

Seemingly it is only available in german (which could be the reason why it was so hard to find out). Back then it seemingly did not have a long run as only a few boxes and books were released. Its purpose was to introduce kids with roleplaying games and also to some core concepts from dsa (english the dark eye).

Comment: If you managed to solve your own question, make sure to mark your own answer as the solution to the problem. :)

Comment: @Phil  tnx forgot about that^^'